# Is usage of the Timer is efficient for server synchronization?

Tags: swift, timer

For my sync issue I need to poll server each 10 seconds. My solution was quite straight forward and I use `Timer`.

Example of the usage:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10, target: BlockOperation { [weak self] in
   self?.refreshBalance()
}, selector: #selector(Operation.main), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

It works fine but there is quite a lot of troubles in case of restore and invalidation of the timer.

Now I have more than 5 timers that have different timeInterval and managing of them is quite complex.

I am looking for suggestion about what are others way of solving of the similar issue? And is really usage of the `Timer` is efficient in this issue?

Comment: Well, usually when you need multiple pollings, it's nicer to create one timer with short interval, e.g. half a second and check all necessary actions inside of it.

Comment: Polling your server every 10 seconds is a terrible idea and your users are going to hate you. Especially those using expensive data plans.

Comment: The right solution is sockets approach if you need near real-time updates while the user is using the app or push notifications if there is some significant event that the user may want to opt-in to while the app isn’t running. Polling is a very inefficient approach.